# Directory.GetFiles(strFolderPath) EXCLUDING Certain File Names VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How would a do a `Directory.GetFiles` and exclude files called "abc" and "xyz"?

Basically I have a DIR where all the files exist and a particular group of files has to be sent to one department and the the "abc" and "xyz" file need to be sent to another?

At the moment I do this:

```
'Standard Documents
Dim strAttachments As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
strAttachments.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(GlobalVariables.strFolderPath))
```

I need the same functionality but excluding the files and then do a similar command as above to include the files to another address.

Cheers,,

James

**UPDATE**

```
Dim exclude = {"ATS_Declaration"}
Dim myFiles = From fn In Directory.EnumerateFiles(GlobalVariables.strFolderPath)
              Where Not exclude.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
Dim strAttachments As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(myFiles)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude files from Directory.EnumerateFiles based on multiple criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285113/exclude-files-from-directory-enumeratefiles-based-on-multiple-criteria)

Comment: Why not iterate over strAttachments and create two lists afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ and [`System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim exclude = { "abc", "xyz" }
Dim myFiles = From fn in Directory.EnumerateFiles(GlobalVariables.strFolderPath)
              Where Not exclude.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnorecase)
Dim strAttachments As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(myFiles)
```

Note that i have used [`EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx) since that does not need to load all into memory first.

Comment: Hi Tim,

I used your code but it is still including my file "ATS_Declaration". do I have to qualify the full path to exclude it or just the filename? (including extension)

Comment: @Lynchie: have you added `ATS_Declaration` to the excluding `string()`? Have you really used the code above, in the very first version i've thought that you want to exclude specific extensions, therefore used `Path.GetExtension`. But now i'm using `GetFileNameWithoutExtension`.

Comment: Hi Tim,

Yes - I will place my updated code in the main question now.

It still includes the file in the strAttachments List.

Comment: @Lynchie: can you post the full file-name? That should work. Maybe there is a hidden character somewhere(white-space etc.).

Comment: dont worry I was being a complete muppet, I had not excluded part of my original query.

Comment: What about if I want to INCLUDE particular files? I take it lose the 'Not' in the Where statement?

Comment: You could create another collection include and use Contains instead of Not Contains. If you want to use both filters concat them with AndAlso.

Comment: can you wildcard this?  it works only for exact matches (Contains is not working as it should)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the answers here to exclude the file (not sure why Contains fails to match unless the file name is exactly the same as the exclusion string)
The answer below works wonderfully

Check this out: [Exclude files from Directory.EnumerateFiles based on multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285113/exclude-files-from-directory-enumeratefiles-based-on-multiple-criteria)